# Using Coinbase OAUTH2 for GDAX Trading?

Tags: coinbase-api

I just set up the coinbase oauth2 authentication for my Flask web application and I currently having it working.

I was wondering if it's possible to use the authentication token for GDAX trading, or if there's an alternative means of doing so?